# problema datepicker y ventana modal bootstrap

Tags: modal, datepicker

tengo el siguiente problema y no he logrado solucionarlo.
Tengo una venta modal bootstrap. dentro el un un input donde se carga el date picker. Funciona bien, pero al momento de seleccionar una fecha, esta no se carga en el input. he probado de todo sin resultados positivos.
aqui parte del codigo.

la venta modal se llama a traves de ajax:

```
$('#asigna-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
var $modal = $(this),
idp = <?php echo $idped?>;
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax/asigna_ped.php',
  data: {"dato" : idp},
  success: function(data) {
      $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
  } 
});
})
```

y dentro de ajax/asigna_ped.php:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datePicker" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calender"></i></span>
```

y su correspondiente funcion.

```
$(function () {
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    minDate: '+5d',
    autoclose: 'true',
    language: 'es',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
})
});
```

si alguien le ha pasado lo mismo o ha logrado solucionar este problema, agradeceria me oriente a como hacerlo. cabe mencionar que las librerias estan insertas en el archivo principal.
como siempre, muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta probar con este codigo:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hola, gracias por responder. el problema sigue. muestra el caledario pero al seleccionar la fecha que necesito o cualquier fecha, no la muestra en el input.

Comment: Que error te muestra en el navegador??

Comment: eso es lo mas extraño, la consola del navegador no muestra error alguno. es como si desapareciera la fecha seleccionada, probe poniendo un z-index al contenedor date pero nada..

Comment: Revisa el css de tu caja de texto, a lo mejor tienes la propiedad "color : #fff;" que es un color blanco. Otra manera de que puedas verificar es inspeccionando elemento a tu caja de texto. Prueba y me cuentas.

Comment: revise css, si fuera ese el caso, al inspeccionar la consola, me deberia mostrar la fecha seleccionada (en la consola), pero no lo hace. es como si la fecha quedara por detras del modal, por eso intente, segun lei en internet, usar la propiedad z-index del contenedor, pero nada de nada.